# Telerik AutoCompleteView Item height

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, telerik

Is there a way to set the telerikRadAutoCompleteView Item-height?
I even read the Telerik documentation, nothing useful found.
it has SuggestionViewHeight Property that sets the result panel height but I want the item height.
[output Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4evTa.jpg)

this is my XAML :

```
<telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteView x:Name="AutoComplete" 
    Style="{StaticResource AutoComplateWatermark}"
    TextSearchPath="Title"
    SuggestionViewHeight="220"
    SuggestionViewBackgroundColor="#787878"
    SuggestionItemTextColor="#E00685"
    VerticalOptions="Center"
    DisplayMode="Plain"
    Watermark="Person">
    <telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteView.SuggestionItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <Grid >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="1*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <Label Text=":D"
                            HorizontalOptions="Center"
                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                            FontSize="18">
                            <Label.TextColor>
                                <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="Color">
                                    <On Platform="iOS">#007AFF</On>
                                    <On Platform="Android, UWP">#2964CE</On>
                                </OnPlatform>
                            </Label.TextColor>
                        </Label>
                    <Grid Grid.Column="2">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="3*"></RowDefinition>
                            <RowDefinition Height="1*"></RowDefinition>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="printing.png" ></Image>
                        <Label Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Text="{Binding Title}" TextColor="White" FontSize="15" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteView.SuggestionItemTemplate>
</telerikInput:RadAutoCompleteView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ViewCell Height will do it.

```
  <ViewCell Height="48">
```

Comment: tnx. I solved the problem using custom AutoCompleteView. just an entry and a listView